# SpringBoot does not read application.properties

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

I am trying to do simple CRUD application by using Hibernate and SpringBoot. I want hibernate to create db automatically and show the sql statements therefore I added some properties in application.properties.

```
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2-console

spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = create-drop
```

But all of them seems unused property. I tried to create configuration class and also added `@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")` but it did not help.

Here my configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
@EnableJpaRepositories
public class DBConfiguration {
}
```

Here is my main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Import({DBConfiguration.class})
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class SpringboothibernateApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringboothibernateApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

What I am doing wrong why application.properties file is unused at all.

Comment: If you have no entities, there are no tables to be created, so of course you will not see any SQL statements printed.

Comment: Ditch the `DbConfiguration` (you don't need it)` as well as the `@Import` and `@PropertySource`. Make sure the `application.properties` is in `src/main/resources` and not in `src/main/java` or in the `src/test` tree.

Comment: There are entities, they are simple POJOs therefore I have not added them to my post. Property file is actually under src/main/resources.

Answer (score 3):

Delete the DbConfiguration. Write those properties in application.properties file which is located in resource folder. then use @EnableAutoConfiguration annotation on SpringBoothibernateApplication class.

Comment: I tried it, actually it was my initial step but i did not help

Comment: -@SpringBootApplication annotation already includes @EnableAutoConfiguration

Answer (score 0):

Restarting STS/Eclipse has solved the problem for me. After restart, it is taking the updated values from application.properties.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).